# Class design for domain object and container of these objects

Tags: java, c++, oop, design-patterns

we were having a discussion today at work about a recurring situation in our codebase:
Say we have a particular domain object in our software (e.g. Customer). Additionally we have a group of customers relevant for a specific use case in our system. We have business logic that works on a specific customer (e.g. getRevenue()) and other parts that work on the whole  group of customers (e.g. getAverageRevenue(), getNumberOfActiveCustomers(),...).
The group functionality also includes methods that changes certain Customers in the group, or that searches for certain sub groups in the group,etc.. (e.g. getCustomersWithoutOrdersSince()).

How would you go about such a situation:

1. Make a Customer class and a CustomerGroup class: The CustomerGroup class has its customers in a private member std::vector (or in Java in a List). Group related functionality is implemented as member functions of CustomerGroup.
2. Make just a Customer class, Leave the std::vector (or List) of customers with the caller: Add single customer functionality in member functions of Customer. CustomerGroup related functionality is realised as static methods of Customer (e.g.: static int getAverageRevenue(vector &custVector) or in Java static int getAverageRevenue(List))
3. Variation of Nr. 2 (C++ only): Make just a Customer class, Leave the vector of customers with the caller implement CustomerGroup functionality as non-member functions in namespace Customer
4. ...

How would you implement such a scenario or what are the advantages/disadvantages in your opinion.

In item 23 of "Effective C++" ("Prefer non-member non-friend functions to members functions") Scott Meyers advocate to move stuff out of classes in non-member functions. This would resemble design number 3 in my opinion. I find this advice odd and counterintuitive however. @jrahhali commented that this might be to adhere to the single responsibility principle. Any thoughts/posts/URL's on that are welcome (unfortunately I didn't find any good discussion on item 23).

Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: 5. Use `std::accumulate` and stop shoehorning everything into a class hierarchy.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: My example is somewhat misleading and contrived. Group functionality is not just providing simple accumulation methods (like getAverageRevenue()) but is also providing functionality that modifies the Customer objects in various ways, searches for subgroups of customers,... I'll update the example to reflect that

Comment: Ah. In that case please consider my answer misleading and contrived, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I like this the best.  It is intuitive to have methods that act on a customer in a Customer class, and its intuitive to have methods that act upon a group on Customers in a CustomerGroup class.  You also have your CustomerGroup encapsulating its representation of a group of customers, and it provides a nice location for all future group-related operations to live.  It's not static, so you have the option of thread safety, if that's important.  CustomerGroup also provides more meaning than just a vector or List.
2. This is also not bad.  You are still providing a place to group related behaviour, but this time in static methods on the Customer class.  I personally think static methods are more procedural like than OO like, and for that reason, still prefer #1.  But, at the end of the day, #1 and #2 are very similar in that they both achieve a DRY approach.
3. This is even more procedural than #2, but still acheives the same result.

I guess the answer depends on how OO and/or procedural you want to code.

Comment: Okay so you say it's more a question of which style to use. When discussing the alternatives I just had the gut feeling that I would definitely go for 1 instead of 2 but besides encapsulation I couldn't think of any "hard" advantages of 1 over 2.

Comment: btw. I came across Meyers "Effective C++" Item 23 "Prefer non-member non-friend functions to members functions". This would (at least for C++) advocate number 2 or 3. Any thoughts on that. In the book Meyers cites compilation unit decoupling as a potential advantage.

Comment: What an intriguing find.  After researching Item 23, I do not understand the argument how externalizing member functions INCREASES encapsulation.  That seems backwards.  The explanations of Item 23 that I read reminds me very much of the Single Responsibility Principle.  Perhaps Meyers was explaining SRP by another name, and didn't know it?  The SRP does not say ALL member functions be stripped from an object, but only those member functions that 'have a reason to change'.

Comment: I had the same impression when reading item 23. At first I thought this might more of a C++ specific thing (unlike java you can have methods existing outside a class, minimizing header dependencies,...) but maybe you are right and it is some kind of reformulated SRP. You reduce the likelihood of change if you reduce the functionality a specific class offers. But then again you still want to group data and functionality together...